Android 14 BLE - WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT vs WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE
My Android and iOS app (react native based) uses BLE to connect to a custom esp32-based peripheral.  It's been working fine for years, but starting with Android 14 some features are not working.
In order to isolate the issues, I'm using a small standalone Android studio project that connects to the peripheral and sends it data.  There is logging on the peripheral side so we can see how much data was received.   The peripheral sets the MTU to 256 on connection.
What I don't understand is this:

If the program sends more than 20 bytes, WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT works fine and all data is received by the peripheral.  However, if the program sends more than 20 bytes and  WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE is used, only 20 bytes are received.

If the MTU is set by the android program and any size message is sent after it is confirmed, NO data is received by the peripheral.  (I suspect this is some kind of munging between the peripheral and Android, so the workaround is to not set it on the android side)


Can anyone explain these behaviors?
I'm aware that Android 14 has changes with regards to the MTUs but it's not clear from the documentation how this is causing these issues.

The first thing you should do is to inspect the HCI log to see on which side the problem is.
